# Use of DB2 Indices with several columns

Tags: entity-framework, indexing, db2, query-optimization

We are trying to locate a performance problem and wondering if an index is being used.

We have a table with a composite key, "ID" and "Version", both integers.

We have a select that tries to find the max of "ID". (This is done via Entity framework if it makes a difference).

Will this use the index or will it do a table scan?

Comment: It might be hard to tell unless we can see both the generated SQL and the table structure and index definitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `ID` column is defined as the first part of a multi-column index, then DB2 will use that index to determine the `MAX()`.  It will still probably try to use the index if you did a `MAX(VERSION)`, but if you have a very large table, this may take quite a bit of processing.

You can confirm this using the [explain facilities](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.perf.doc/doc/c0005135.html) (link is for Linux/Unix/Windows 9.7).